# Variable returns as undefined when trying to filter items in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which was using local state and worked correctly, while trying to implement it in redux it gets returned as undefined. What is the best solution to compare these two arrays and receive only the users who are not current users.

```
import { FETCH_USERS_TO_ADD } from './types';
import axios from 'axios'

export const fetchUsersToAdd = () => dispatch => {
var userBox = [];
var newUserBox = [];
let newUserIds = {};
let newUsersArr = [];

    axios.all([
        axios.get('/updateUserList'),
        axios.get('/userInformation')
        ])
        .then(axios.spread((newUsers, currentUsers) => {
            userBox.push(newUsers.data)
            console.log('userbox '+ userBox)
            newUserBox.push(currentUsers.data)
            console.log('newuserbox ' + newUserBox)
// Save all user Ids in object
            for (let newUser of newUserBox){
                newUserIds[newUser.id] = newUser.id
                console.log( 'these are uxser ids' + newUser.id)
              }
// Compare new users with previous user ids and push new users in an array
              for (let user of userBox){
                if(!newUserIds[user.staffID]){
                console.log(user)
                  newUsersArr.push(user)
                  console.log('new user arr' + newUsersArr)
                }

              }
              dispatch({
                type: FETCH_USERS_TO_ADD,
                payload: newUsersArr
            })
        }))


}
```

When Logging the ids they return as undefined in the for loop. I want to compare users and if they arent already in the userBox array (checked by Id) send them to new user array.

The Correct Solution WIll Give Me Only Two Items Once Filtered:

```
     0: Array(9)
0: {staffID: 1, dept: "Junior Web Developer", email: "manasaN@tpionline.com", name: "manasa", password: "$2y$10$/zYS7OhzwdLOi6Slzc3Rv.aJdy1J6MjnLCN24GmZ3rMHWUS"}
1: {staffID: 2, dept: "Web Developer", email: "juliof@tpionline.net", name: "Julio Fajardo", password: "$2y$10$MphAC8aRY2uzs1ZEduvCqK1/1nd7t0KukEkvGbx5Y4van.Da6"}
2: {staffID: 3, dept: "Fake Title", email: "johnf@tpionline.com", name: "John Fester", password: "$2y$10$/oa/ESQmhhc5WvxrQKoUU.PjdZY5FccilGfCUL5eyeOU5IDSa"}
3: {staffID: 5, dept: "Fake Title", email: "fakeguy@gmail.net", name: "Test", password: "$2y$10$VWnnw5gRTN2absWos04fsOixW6dbFqsFZL8oPiJm"}
4: {staffID: 6, dept: "Conf room", email: "conf2@gmail.com", name: "Conf 1st floor", password: "$2y$10$KAZa1k2Sd/rg6dnVeqw4duB/XbAdze6Zle3ZhcMaRphloG."}
5: {staffID: 8, dept: "Fake Title", email: "newguy@gmail.net", name: "New guy", password: ""}
6: {staffID: 9, dept: "Fake Title", email: "nguy@gmail.net", name: "New Guy2", password: ""}
7: {staffID: 20, dept: "Erwing", email: "erwingh@tpionline.com", name: "Erwing Hernandez", password: "$2y$10$RWgOBbUHojgmyk3behYhd.kzdFEiH.6d70pS5q5Gf3ZYEa"}
8: {staffID: 12, dept: "Conf room", email: "cristinab@tpionline.com", name: "Cristina Bermudez", password: "$2y$10$92I6fSJY6OW001cdaeF5tdHBjWHBmoCvX1RnfhTspjpBa"}


    0: {id: 1, firstName: "Elton", lastName: "Frederick", departmentId: 1, admin: true, …}
1: {id: 2, firstName: "Julio", lastName: "Probando", departmentId: 1, admin: false, …}
2: {id: 3, firstName: "Corey", lastName: "Chris", departmentId: 2, admin: false, …}
3: {id: 4, firstName: "Daisy", lastName: "Ramos", departmentId: 3, admin: false, …}
4: {id: 5, firstName: "Test", lastName: "User", departmentId: 0, admin: false, …}
5: {id: 6, firstName: "Tes2t", lastName: "Use2r", departmentId: 3, admin: false, …}
6: {id: 7, firstName: "Air Car Hotel", lastName: "Nunca", departmentId: 4, admin: false, …}
7: {id: 8, firstName: "Jenn", lastName: "Lee", departmentId: 4, admin: false, …}
8: {id: 9, firstName: "Reyna", lastName: "Pagan", departmentId: 5, admin: false, …}
9: {id: 10, firstName: "Ameilia", lastName: "Rodriguez", departmentId: 6, admin: false, …}
```

I Should End Up WIth

```
 0: {staffID: 20, dept: "Erwing", email: "erwingh@tpionline.com", name: "Erwing Hernandez", password: "$2y$10$RWgOBbUHojgmyk3behYhd.kzdFEiH.6BBaxn4B070pS5q5Gf3ZYEa"}
1: {staffID: 12, dept: "Test ADD", email: "cristinab@tpionline.com", name: "Cristina Bermudez", password: "$2y$10$92I6fSJY6OW001caJJmeReHnaeF5tdHBjWHBmoCvX1RnfhTspjpBa"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { FETCH_USERS_TO_ADD } from './types';
import axios from 'axios'

export const fetchUsersToAdd = () => dispatch => {
    axios.all([
        axios.get('/updateUserList'),
        axios.get('/userInformation')
        ])
        .then(([newUserBox, currentUserBox]) => {
              const newUserIds = new Set(newUserBox.map(({ id }) => id));
              dispatch({
                type: FETCH_USERS_TO_ADD,
                payload: currentUserBox.filter(({ staffID }) => newUserIds.has(staffID))
            })
        })
}
```

1.) Removed `axios.spread()` and replaced with regular ol' ES6 way.

2.) Removed first loop and used ES6 set instead of object. We're dealing with a collection of unique ids (set), not key/value pairs (object). An object would work fine too, but doesn't really describe what is going on. And is more lines :). We pass the constructor for `Set` an array of ids. `Map()` returns a transformed array, so we're mapping over `newUserBox` and returning a new array that just consists of the id and passing that into a new Set.

3.) Removed second loop which is supposed to filter elements. Like #2 where we subbed out a generic loop/global variables for Set+ map functions, instead of a generic loop to filter here we can use an already-existing function: filter. Filter takes a callback that is passed every item in the array. A new array is returned with only the items that the callback returns true on. So in this case, we're only keeping items with a staffId contained in `newUserIds` (`.has() returns true or false`)

Comment: I updated the post with the info that it should return, this doesnt return what im looking for.

Comment: Just tweaked it a bit, if it still has problems try posting your newUsers/currentUsers to compare